# Change Axis Line color in Chart created using chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

[Chart Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LUhsZ.png)

I have created the above chart using chart.js library.
I want to change the horizontal and the vertical axis colors in this chart.
I have tried 'scaleFontColor' but it changes color of only labels.

```
var myBarChart = new Chart(ctx).Bar(data, { scaleFontColor: "white" });
```

Is there any other property for changing the color of horizontal and vertical axis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6bjy9nxh/) with an example chart in it.

You can change the axes color with the property:

```
{
    scaleLineColor: "red"
}
```

Comment: No worries, if you could accept as answer that would be great :)